# Required Files for VB.NET Program to be included in Installer

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, relative-path

I am finishing off a VB.Net Windows Application and want to make it extremely simple for the user to install onto their machine.
The program uses 2 Microsoft Excel documents as templates, as well as a 'save to' folder.
I need these to be accessable no matter where the installer goes and to what machine.
I have already made my paths relative in the program:

```
Dim ClassFolder As String = Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "SaveToFolder\")
Dim ClassTemplate As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Templates\TemplateFile.xlsx"
```

Please help as I am inexperienced with this area, 
Thank you so much.

Comment: One option is to add the excel files as resources inside the executable, then the first time your app is run to create the necessary folders and write the excel files to disk. That way all installation requires is to copy the EXE file to the new PC

Comment: In your installer, create your 2 folders  inside the Application Folder. Then add the excel file inside the Templates folder. You can view the Application Folder by right clicking on your setup project -> View -> File System. This way when the user installs your application the folders and the excel file are automatically created

Comment: Play around with file systems

Comment: Thank you heaps guys. I got it all working! Turns out that if there is an empty folder in the Applications Folder, it doesn't install it. This is why it couldn't find the correct path for the 'savetofolder'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new Setup project.
2. Right Click on set up project and View> File Systems

[image]

3. A file system window will open. Right Click on Application folder 
   [image]
4. A browse file dialog will open. Select the files you want to add in setup. Change you program according to the path.
   [image]